# Get *all* shapes (including nested groups) in active presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

My question comes from the need to change all text fonts the a specific font A. I know that there is a "Change font..." option in PowerPoint, but it forces me to pick a "from font" and a "to font". In my case there are several different fonts which should a be changed to font "X". Thus I wrote the following VBA macro.

```
Private Sub Set_Font_Of_All_TextFrames(oShp As Shape, font As String)
' Go through all shapes on all slides. This is a recurisve function. First call needs to pass "Nothing" to oShp.
' Any font in every textframe that is not "font" will be set to "font".
' The recursion is necessary in order to go through groups.
' BUG/TODO: Text in Master is not included so far!

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Integer

    If oShp Is Nothing Then ' first subroutine call
        For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                    Set_Font_Of_All_TextFrames shp, font ' recursive call in case of group
                Else
                    Set_Font shp, font ' else change font
                End If
            Next shp
        Next sld
    ' in case of recursive calls:
    ElseIf oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
        For i = 1 To oShp.GroupItems.Count()
            Set shp = oShp.GroupItems.Item(i)
            Set_Font_Of_All_TextFrames shp, font ' another recursive call in case of group; will repeat this branch in case of subgroup
        Next
    Else
        Set shp = oShp
        Set_Font shp, font   ' else change font
    End If
End Sub
```

The 'Set_Font(shp as Shape, font as String)' subroutine is just to avoid redundancy. It simply checks if the given `shp` has text with any other font than `font` and changes it. At some place, `Set_Font_Of_All_TextFrames Nothing "X"` is called. It works as expected, but the following questions arise:

1) How can I make this functionality available for other operations than changing fonts? Do I really have to copy-paste all this?

2) Can I use a function to walk through all shapes and groups like in my function but instead of calling the `set_font` subroutine, it populates a list with references to all shapes it can find? This list I can pass to the e.g. `set_font` subroutine (and any other which should perform an action on all shapes)?

3) Why are shapes on the master excluded from my function?

Comment: 1) Other operations: The slide/shape loops you're using are a pretty standard PowerPoint VBA technique. You can use it to make all kinds of other changes to a deck. Please let us know what other operations you want to try. 2) You can't set properties simultaneously to a list (You would creating a 2-dimensional array). Even with an array, you still have to apply new properties one shape at a time. 3) Masters and Layouts aren't part of the ActivePresentation.Slides collection.

Comment: A better practice than changing each text instance to a specific font would be to apply the theme fonts to all shapes. That makes future font updates possible from the user interface instead of through code. This page has a macro that does that: http://youpresent.co.uk/change-powerpoint-fonts-to-theme-fonts/

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thanks for the link. We are usually using a theme, but we have special situations where we need to export the slides with another font, so we need to change them to a specific one and not the "theme font". Do I see correctly that the code in the link doesn't support nested groups?

Comment: @JohnKorchok ad1) Thanks for the confirmation. If you say that this is the way to go, I feel more comfortable doing it that way. It felt so...wrong somehow. I really only wanted to get all shapes at hand to do whatever I please. Setting fonts, deleting them, whatever... consider it to be a utility function to give you all shapes in all (sub)groups. I tinkered on it a bit more and provide my results as one possible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I discovered that this is more or less the way to go. I post here my "ulitity function" to produce a collection of all shapes (including all shapes in arbitrarily nested subgroups) that can be used and iterated through in any other function or subroutine.

Simple version that goes through all slides in the active presentation (it also clearly show how the function is supposed to operate):

```
Function Get_All_Shapes(oShp As Shape, oColl As Collection)
' Go through all shapes on all slides. This is a recursive function. First call needs to pass "Nothing" to oShp and oColl.
' The collection oColl will be populated with all shapes (including all shapes in all groups) in the presentation.
' The return parameter will be the gradually populated collection.
' The recursion is necessary in order to go through groups.

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Integer

    If oShp Is Nothing And oColl Is Nothing Then ' first function call
        Set oColl = New Collection
        For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                    Set oColl = Get_All_Shapes(shp, oColl)  ' recursive call in case of group
                Else
                    oColl.Add shp ' else add shape to collection
                End If
            Next shp
        Next sld
    ' in case of recursive calls:
    ElseIf oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
        For i = 1 To oShp.GroupItems.Count()
            Set shp = oShp.GroupItems.Item(i)
            Set oColl = Get_All_Shapes(shp, oColl) ' another recursive call in case of group; will repeat this branch in case of subgroup
        Next
    Else
        oColl.Add oShp ' else add shape to collection
    End If
    Set Get_All_Shapes = oColl ' set populated collection as function return parameter
End Function
```

Here is a more refined version that lets you choose whether to populate the collection with only selected shapes (and nested subgroups) and if the master slide with its custom layouts should be included into the collection:

```
Function Get_All_Shapes_WIP(oShp As Shape, oColl As Collection, Optional onlySelected As Boolean = False, Optional includeMaster As Boolean = False)
' Go through all shapes on all slides. This is a recursive function. First call needs to pass "Nothing" to oShp and oColl.
' The collection oColl will be populated with all shapes (including all shapes in all groups) in the presentation.
' The return parameter will be the gradually populated collection.
' The recursion is necessary in order to go through groups.
' If onlySelected is True, only the selected shapes will be added to the collection.
' If includeMaster is True, shapes on the master slide and all custom layouts will be added to the collection. This behavior is not affected by the value of onlySelected.

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Integer

    ' first function call (main loops)
    If oShp Is Nothing And oColl Is Nothing Then
        Set oColl = New Collection

        ' presentation loops
        If onlySelected = False Then ' all shapes on all slides
            For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
                For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                    If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                        Set oColl = Get_All_Shapes_WIP(shp, oColl, onlySelected, includeMaster) ' recursive call in case of group
                    Else
                        oColl.Add shp ' else add shape to collection
                    End If
                Next shp
            Next sld

        Else ' onlySelected = True
            For Each shp In ActiveWindow.selection.ShapeRange
                If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                    Set oColl = Get_All_Shapes_WIP(shp, oColl, onlySelected, includeMaster) ' recursive call in case of group
                Else
                    oColl.Add shp ' else add shape to collection
                End If
            Next shp
        End If

        ' master loops
        If includeMaster = True Then ' add also slide master shapes to the collection
            ' master shapes
            For Each shp In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes
                If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                    Set oColl = Get_All_Shapes_WIP(shp, oColl, onlySelected, includeMaster) ' recursive call in case of group
                Else
                    oColl.Add shp ' else add shape to collection
                End If
            Next shp
            ' custom layouts shapes
            For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count()
                For Each shp In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Item(i).Shapes
                If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                    Set oColl = Get_All_Shapes_WIP(shp, oColl, onlySelected, includeMaster) ' recursive call in case of group
                Else
                    oColl.Add shp ' else add shape to collection
                End If
                Next shp
            Next
        End If

    ' recursive calls:
    ElseIf oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
        For i = 1 To oShp.GroupItems.Count()
            Set shp = oShp.GroupItems.Item(i)
            Set oColl = Get_All_Shapes_WIP(shp, oColl, onlySelected, includeMaster) ' another recursive call in case of group; will repeat this branch in case of subgroup
        Next
    Else
        oColl.Add oShp ' else add shape to collection
    End If

    Set Get_All_Shapes_WIP = oColl ' set (partially) populated collection as function return parameter in every call
End Function
```

Example of usage:

```
Sub Set_All_Fonts_To_Calibri()
' Sets the font of all text in all shapes in the presentation to "Calibri".

    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = Get_All_Shapes_WIP(Nothing, Nothing, onlySelected:=False, includeMaster:=True)
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In coll
        Set_Font shp, "Calibri"
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I'm sure others will find this useful.